# Python Factorial Program - Printing the Equation

Tags: python

I am writing a program that calculates the factorial of a number, I am able to display the correct answer, however along with the answer I need the actual calculation to display, I am having trouble with that.  So for example, when the user enters 4, I need it to display as:

I have been trying to figure out the right code, but do not know what to do.

Here is the code I have so far

number = int(input("Enter a number to take the factorial of: "))

```
factorial = 1
for i in range(1, number + 1):
factorial = factorial * i

print (factorial)
```

Right now, it displays the correct answer, however I need for it to include the equation as well as follows: 4! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 = 24

Comment: hint: construct the string as you are iterating.

Comment: I am not sure what that means as I am new to this.  Would I have to create a new line of code for that?  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to construct the string as you are iterating:

```
equation = str(number) + "! = "

factorial = 1
for i in range(1, number + 1):
    factorial = factorial * i
    equation += str(i) + "x"

equation = equation[:-1] + " = " + str(factorial)
print(equation)
```

Note that this method appends an unwanted 'x' after the last factor. This is removed by `equation[:-1]`.

Alternatively, you could append this one-line solution to the end of your code. It uses the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method of the string class to concatenate an array of strings:

```
print(str(number) + "! = " + "x".join(str(n) for n in range(1, number + 1)) + " = " + str(factorial))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you loop through the numbers to be multiplied, you can append each number's character to a string containing the equation, e.g ans, and print it at last. At the end of the code, I omitted the last letter because I didn't want an extra 'x' to be displayed.

```
def fact(number):
    num_string=str(number)
    factorial = 1
    ans=num_string+"!="
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        factorial = factorial * i
        ans+=str(i)+"x"
    ans=ans[:-1]
    print(ans)
    return factorial
fact(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append each value to the list and then print the equation using the f-string:

```
num = 5
l = []
f = 1
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    f *= i
    l.append(i)

print(f"{num}! = {' x '.join(map(str, l))} = {f}")
# 5! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 = 120
```